# Three equivalent forms of stable manifold theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I've seen three forms of stable manifold theorem, one in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_manifold_theorem), one [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2019/REUPapers/Cardinal.pdf) a lecture note and another one in Pilyugin's textbook of dynamical systems:

1. In wiki, it is stated that: $p$ is a hyperbolic point of a smooth map $f$. $W^s(p)$ and $W^u(p)$ are stable and unstable sets. Then $W^s(p)$ is a smooth manifold and its tangent space has the same dimension as the stable space of the linearization of $f$ at $p$. $W^u(p)$ is a smooth manifold and its tangent space has the same dimension as the unstable space of the linearization of $f$ at $p$.
2. In lecture note, it is stated that: $p$ is a hyperbolic point of a $C^r$ map $f: R^2 \rightarrow R^2$. There exists a $C^r$ curve $\gamma: B(p, \epsilon) \rightarrow R^2$ such that the graph of $\gamma$ is the set of all points that converge to $p$.
3. In Pilyugin's book, it is stated that: $x = 0$ is a hyperbolic point of a diffeomorphism $f$, then $\exists \epsilon > 0$, neighborhood $U$ of origin, s.t. there exists a mapping $\gamma: \{ y: |y| < \epsilon \} \rightarrow U$ of class $C^1$ s.t.

   (1) $\gamma(0) = 0$, $\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial y}(0) = 0$;

   (2) the surface $\Gamma = \{ (y, \gamma(y)): |y| < \epsilon \}$ has the following property: if $x \in \Gamma$, then $f^k(x) \rightarrow 0$, $k \rightarrow \infty$.

   Also we can get that if $|f^k(x)| < \epsilon$ for $k \geq 0$, then $x \in \Gamma$.

Why are these three forms equivalent?